# php fetch your details from the database via email

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make a text field and button that will allow the user to fetch his details on the text fields  instead of writting his details every time he wants to make a new reservation.

like in this picture:
http://oi41.tinypic.com/23ie70j.jpg

I tried to make this but with my code but gives me double forms one with the details and one without.

```
<form method="post" action="reserv page.php">
enter  the email: <input type = "text"  name = "email"/>   
<input type = "submit"  name = "submit"  value="submit" />  
</form>
<?php  
mysql_connect("localhost","userName","password");
mysql_select_db("database_Name");

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$q  = "SELECT * FROM tabe WHERE the_email  = '$email'"; 
$run = mysql_query($q );

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($run))
{ 
?>

</br></br>

<form action="payment.php" method="post" >
First Name:<input name="fName" type="text" value="<?php echo $row[1];   ?>" />
Last Name: <input name="lNamet" type="text" value="<?php echo $row[2];   ?>" />
User Name: <input name="uName" type="text" value="<?php echo $row[3];   ?>"/>
Email:     <input name="email" type="text" value="<?php echo $row[4];   ?>" />
password:  <input name="pass" type="password" value="<?php echo $row[5];  ?>"/>  
contact:   <input name="number" type="text" value="<?php echo $row[6];   ?>" />

<input name="confirm" type="submit" value="Confirm" />
</form>

</br></br>

<?php
}}
?>

<form action="payment.php" method="post" >
First Name:<input name="fName" type="text"  />
Last Name: <input name="lNamet" type="text" />
User Name: <input name="uName" type="text" />
Email:     <input name="email" type="text"  />
password:  <input name="pass" type="password" />  
contact:   <input name="number" type="text"  />

<input name="confirm" type="submit" value="Confirm" />
</form>
```

Comment: Look at your code carefully. You're outputting your form in a `while()` loop. Why are you using `while`?

Comment: QUICK! Arm the SQL injectors!

Comment: You are **wide open** to SQL injection attacks, and **you will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  Learn to use prepared/parameterized queries with PDO or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form method="post" action="reserv page.php">
enter  the email: <input type = "text"  name = "email"/>   
<input type = "submit"  name = "submit"  value="submit" />  
</form>
<?php  
mysql_connect("localhost","userName","password");
mysql_select_db("database_Name");

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $email = $_POST['email']; 
    //limit the query to one entry :)
    $q  = "SELECT * FROM tabe WHERE the_email  = '$email' LIMIT 1"; 
    $run = mysql_query($q );

    //check if email is registered
    if(mysql_num_rows($run)>0) 
    {
        //display filled up form
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($run))
        { 
        ?>

        </br></br>

        <form action="payment.php" method="post" >
        First Name:<input name="fName" type="text" value="<?php echo $row[1];   ?>" />
        Last Name: <input name="lNamet" type="text" value="<?php echo $row[2];   ?>" />
        User Name: <input name="uName" type="text" value="<?php echo $row[3];   ?>"/>
        Email:     <input name="email" type="text" value="<?php echo $row[4];   ?>" />
        password:  <input name="pass" type="password" value="<?php echo $row[5];  ?>"/>  
        contact:   <input name="number" type="text" value="<?php echo $row[6];   ?>" />

        <input name="confirm" type="submit" value="Confirm" />
        </form>

        </br></br>

        <?php
        }
    }
    //display blank form
    else{
        ?>

        <form action="payment.php" method="post" >
        First Name:<input name="fName" type="text"  />
        Last Name: <input name="lNamet" type="text" />
        User Name: <input name="uName" type="text" />
        Email:     <input name="email" type="text"  />
        password:  <input name="pass" type="password" />  
        contact:   <input name="number" type="text"  />

        <input name="confirm" type="submit" value="Confirm" />
        </form>   
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: when I run the code the first thing show up is just the field that ask you enter the email. but how to make also these fields:  First Name
 Last Name:
 User Name:
 Email:     
 password:    
 contact:show up blank and when I enter the email the fields will be filled with information.

Comment: You can add an else clause for the 
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
part. Then display the blank form in that case.

Comment: No problem! Don't forget to hit the 'answered' checkmark to indicate correct answers, and the up arrow for answers you like. This will increase the likelihood of your future questions being answered.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting 2 forms because you're echoing one form if `$_POST['submit']` is set and then another one regardless of anything. Print the second form only if `$_POST['submit']` is not set. Since your code is so poorly written I will just give you an example:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    PRINT FETCHED FORM
}else{
    PRINT EMPTY FORM
}
```

This, however, is not the "right" way to go. What people actually do is have variables null'd at start and then fill them up with data if there's a request and have a single form written in the file with input values as those variables.